# How to include Symfony2 components within a symfony 1.4 application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have an application written in symfony 1.4, and I'd like to use the Symfony2 Serializer component. Is it possible to begin with ? And what should I do to be able to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 is composed of two main features: `component` and `bundle`. You are mixing this two concept in your question. Components are stand-alone and thus independent of each others, but can optionally make use of other components to enhance their possibilities. On the opposite, bundles usually use components to achieve their tasks. They can be dependent of each others and they all depend on the `FrameworkBundle`. The `FrameworkBundle` ties together multiple components, it's a kind of glue between components. The `FrameworkBundle` with other bundles like `DoctrineBundle` and the components form Symfony2.

Since Symfony2 components are stand-alone they can be used with any projects. There is no reason why it would not be possible to use the Serializer component within symfony 1.4.

There is not much documentation on using components of Symfony2 independently. I know they have a PEAR channel so it is simply a matter of getting the library via PEAR and add entry to the autoloader and use classes defined in the component.

I didn't see any README for the serializer component, you may need to look at the code to check how you can use it. Here some links to documentation related to the subject, not specially on serializer.

- Symfony2 components page: [here](http://symfony.com/components)
- Symfony2 PEAR channels: [here](http://pear.symfony.com/)
- Serializer component github: [here](https://github.com/symfony/Serializer)
- Fabien Potencier's blog on what is Symfony2: [here](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's clearer now. I edited the title to be more precise. Thanks for the links too, I'm now going to smoothly introduce Symfony 2 in my projects thanks to these components.